# Программа для предоставления прав администратора файлу

Tags: файлы, cmd, консоль, bat, права-доступа

Нужен bat файл или программа, которая будет давать файлу права администратора, и по возможности добавлять в автозагрузку.

Т.е человек запустил программу, она попросила права администратора, и в дальнейшем данный файл всегда когда запускался, запускался бы с правами администратора.

Я не очень хорошо понимаю в этом, поэтому допускаю, что в некоторых моментах написал чушь.

Comment: Powershell Start Notepad.exe -ArgumentList “c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts” -Verb Runas

Comment: https://www.robotronic.de/elevateen.html

Comment: можете создать в планировщике задачу с повышенными привилегиями и подцепить на событие вход пользователя или загрузка пк.